# Facing "Forbidden Error 403" error when hit .html files in GCS bucket

Tags: google-cloud-platform, google-cloud-storage

I have created one GCS bucket where html files are uploaded. Only employees in my organisation should be able to access those files from browser by hitting the object url's.

I have given "storage object viewer" access to their emails. But the issue is whenever someone tries to access that url, they get "Forbidden Error 403".

Same thing i tried in another GCP projects, they can access tho url's there. I am facing this issue in only my organisation's GCP project.

Is there any extra policy that might have been enables?
How can i troubleshoot this issue?

Answer (score 1):

What kind of permissions did you have set on the bucket - uniform or fine-grained?
[image]

If you have used fine-grained than on each file you have to set the proper permission. If you want to just use your bucket to serve a page in serverless manner just set up Uniform permissions on a bucket and set allUsers to Storage Object Viewer.